# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a nonempty set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U$ is closed under addition for every $u$ in $U$, $-u$ is also in $U$ but U is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$

What I understand from the question is I need to give an example such that the set is closed under addition but not under scalar multiplication.

For this I thought of some sets like $\{(x,y)|x\geq0, y\geq 0\}$ but this does not satisfy the statement " $-u$ is also in $U$ "

Can someone please give an example for this question. Thank you.

Comment: $\lbrace (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x,y\neq 0\rbrace$

Comment: @Senna: that set is not cosed under addition: $(1,1)+(-1,-1)=(0,0)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the subset of all pairs of rational numbers in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then this subset, $\mathbb{Q}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ contains the $\textbf{0}$ vector and is closed under vector addition. Also, give any rational number, its negative is also a rational number, so therefore if $\textbf{u} \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ then $-\textbf{u} \in \mathbb{Q}^2$

However, $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not closed under scalar multiplication over $\mathbb{R}$, and so $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

For example, $(2,7) \in \mathbb{Q}^2$ but $\pi(2,7) = (2 \pi, 7 \pi) \notin \mathbb{Q}^2$

Comment: I suppose $\mathbb Z^2$ would also work

Comment: Any lattice would certainly work. Or any proper and nonzero subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. $\mathbb{Z}$) stuffed into just one of the two coordinates, with the other coordinate zero.

Comment: @leslietownes:  or $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb R$

Answer (score 2):

Consider  $s$ ={(x,y): x is rational} in $R^2$
All conditions valid that you ask but not a subspace of $R^2$ as not closed under scalar multiplication.